# intersecting to files by several columns using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two big CSV files that look like below:

f1.csv

```
f1_c1,f1_c2
A,B
C,A
B,D
```

f2.csv

```
f2_c1,f2_c2,f2_c3
chr1,fail,A
chr1,pass,B
chr1,neutral,C
chr2,fail,D
```

I want to intersect the two files in a way that the information from the first column and the second column of file two should be written for each row of f1 in separate columns. So based on what I mentioned the desired output should be as below:

```
f1_c1,f1_c2,f2_c1,f2_c1,f2_c2,f2_c2
A,B,chr1,chr1,fail,pass
C,A,chr1,chr1,neutral,fail
B,D,chr1,chr2,pass,fail
```

I have been trying to make this code work but it gives errors - would be great if you give some help to fix this.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{gene[$3]=$1; type{$3]=$2; next}{ print ($1, $2, gene[$1], gene[$2], type[$1], type[$2] ) }' f2.csv f1.csv
```

Thank you.

Comment: `type{$3]=$2` should be `type[$3]=$2`.. also, you need to take care of header

Comment: Hello @Apex, could you please do mention how `pass` or `fail` entry is coming in output? Is it from 2 files you are comparing? Kindly elaborate more on it, thank you.

Comment: Hello @RavinderSingh13 - they are coming from the file2 - so basically for each element in file on I want to write the information from the file2. The column names should be general in the code so I can use the code with different column names in the future :) thank you

Comment: When you post code you want help with, never just say `it gives errors` (which is just another variant of the dreaded `it doesn't work`). Post the actual error messages to help us help you debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print "f1_c1,f1_c2,f2_c1,f2_c1,f2_c2,f2_c2"} FNR==NR {m1[$3]=$1; m2[$3]=$2; next} FNR>1 {print $0, m1[$1], m1[$2], m2[$1], m2[$2]}' f2.csv f1.csv

f1_c1,f1_c2,f2_c1,f2_c1,f2_c2,f2_c2
A,B,chr1,chr1,fail,pass
C,A,chr1,chr1,neutral,fail
B,D,chr1,chr2,pass,fail
```

Expanded command:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR == 1 {
   print "f1_c1,f1_c2,f2_c1,f2_c1,f2_c2,f2_c2"
}
FNR == NR {
   m1[$3]=$1
   m2[$3]=$2;
   next
}
FNR > 1 {
   print $0, m1[$1], m1[$2], m2[$1], m2[$2]
}' f2.csv f1.csv
```